# Foreach loop doesn't work but it gets 2 items from my array?

Tags: php, html

i made this foreach loop but it just doesn't show me anything on the screen doesn anybody see what the problem is?
There're 2 items of the array $data['page']['children']

```
<?php foreach ($data['page']['childeren'] as $news): ?>
                <div class="donerenNews">
                    <div class="doneren-image">
                        <img class="group list-group-image doneren-image" src="<?php echo $site_url ?>assets/img/placeholderSubPage.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption doneren-tekst-left">
                        <h1>
                            <?php echo $news['title'] ?>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $news['description'] ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `foreach ($data['page']['childeren'] ` change this to children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you put childreren instead of children in

```
foreach ($data['page']['childeren']
```

so change it to

```
foreach ($data['page']['children']
```